# how to mysqli inner join with 3 tables

Tags: php, mysqli

In the end I need results to contain all data from all 3 tables. How to join the 3 tables so all is present in the end. Here is what I have so far:

```
if ($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM HWData
                        LEFT JOIN ClassData
                        ON HWData.class = ClassData.class
                        LEFT JOIN Judges
                        ON Judges.groupnum = ClassData.groupnum
                        ORDER BY HWData.entrynum",
                        MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
$result_set = mysqli_fetch_all($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result_set);
```

The results are not as expected. It's odd that `console.log[i]['groupnum'];` shows correct groupnum but `$("#output").append("<p>"+data[i]['groupnum']);` shows only 1's

3 tables as follows:

**ClassData**

```
groupnum    abbr
0   DQB
0   DQC
1   SUM
1   PP
1   FOS
1   VANF
1   VANS
2   AFCF
2   AFCS
2   ICCS
2   CCS
3   LSUF
3   LTMS
4   HL
4   MC
```

**Judges**

```
judge   group
Coleen  4
Daniel  3
Aaron   2
Jeff    1
```

**HWData**

```
entrynum    fname   class
1   Esteban FOS
2   Dalia   PP
3   Sheri
4   Sheri   HL
5   Sheri   MC
10  Danita  ICCS
11  Chris   AFCS
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question here. Are you trying to get three different information for three different table in one query or execute three different query and put the information together into the JSON ?

Comment: good question, didn't know i could aggregate the JSON like that. My thought was to make 1 SQL query joining all three tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i figured out you can use multiple joins.

```
if ($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM HWData
                           LEFT JOIN ClassData
                           ON HWData.Abbr = ClassData.Abbr
                           LEFT JOIN Judges
                           ON Judges.groupnum = ClassData.groupnum",
                            MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
$result_set = mysqli_fetch_all($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result_set);
$results->close();
}
```